# Two questions: Crontabs and file overwritning

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

why when I use this line on the crontab, I get error?

Line:`0 1/2 * * * cd public_html/wp-content/plugins && ./16134.bash`

Error: `errors in crontab file, can't install.`

I have created this line with http://crontab.guru/ help, but it didn't work, I want to make crontab to execute command at 0th minute of 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21 and 23 hour.

Lines like these does work:`0 */2 * * * cd public_html/wp-content/plugins && ./16134.bash`

Also, now, to replace data of the file I use this combination, first empty the file `cat/dev/null>16134.txt`, secondly, add to the file what py is outputing `./16134.py >> 16134.txt`. The problem is that when I run these commands, after emptying of the file, python execution takes like 2-5 seconds, so the file is blank for that 2-5 secons and that makes the output on my website also blank, so that's why it would be nice to get an alternative for replacing.

Thanks for read, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ensure there is a newline at the end of your crontab.

Comment: If you have two separate questions they should be placed in separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man 5 crontab`:

```
Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with
``/<number>'' specifies skips of the number's value through the range.  For
example, ``0-23/2'' can be used in the hours field to specify command
execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is
``0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22''). Steps are also permitted after an
asterisk, so if you want to say ``every two hours'', just use ``*/2''.
```

So `/2` must follow a range of values. In your case, you want to run the command every other hour in the 1-23 range, so `1-23/2` would work.